# Set user agent in WebServiceGatewaySupport

Tags: spring, user-agent

How to set user agent in Spring's `WebServiceGatewaySupport`? Here is what I have already tried but failed:

```
@Bean
    public DiscreteGateway discreteGateway() throws SOAPException {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
        Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertyMap.put("User-Agent", "Tough-User");
        SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL));
        messageFactory.setMessageProperties(propertyMap);
        DiscreteGateway discreteGateway = new DiscreteGateway();
        discreteGateway.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
        discreteGateway.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
        discreteGateway.setMessageFactory(messageFactory);
        discreteGateway.setDefaultUri(Discrete_URI);
        return discreteGateway;
    }
```

note that `DiscreteGateway` extends `WebServiceGatewaySupport`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https) is that all I have to do is to set in VM args `http.agent=MY_AGENT` and it worked.